# Visual Basic Console Application Download Percentage?

Tags: vb.net, download, webclient

I am using DownloadFileAsync to download a larger file (1.3 GB), but i'd like to add a simple percentage indicator (ex. 64%). I'm new to Visual Basic I have no idea how to do this.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `WebClient` class has a [`DownloadProgressChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.downloadprogresschanged.aspx) event that you can listen to if you want to update a progresss display. For instance, if you’ve got a console application, it’s as simple as:

```
Dim client As New WebClient()
AddHandler client.DownloadProgressChanged, AddressOf ProgressUpdate
client.DownloadFileAsync(yourURI, yourFile)
```

```
Sub ProgressUpdate(sender As Object, e As DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs)
    ' Reset cursor position …
    Console.CursorTop -= 1
    Console.CursorLeft = 0
    Console.WriteLine("{0}% completed", e.ProgressPercentage)
End Sub
```

If, on the other hand, you are on a `Form` in a WinForms project and you’ve got a label `ProgressLabel` that you want to update, the following code will do that:

```
Sub ProgressUpdate(sender As Object, e As DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs)
    Dim s = String.Format("{0}% completed", e.ProgressPercentage)
    Me.Invoke(New Action(Sub()
                             ProgressLabel.Text = s
                         End Sub))
End Sub
```

The `ProgressUpdate` method is a bit complicated due to multithreading:

The `WebClient` is running the asynchronous file download in a background thread. However, form controls can only be updated from the foreground thread that the form is running in. For that reason, we cannot update the label directly inside the `ProgressUpdate` event (because that, too, is being invoked, and running, in the background thread<sup>1</sup>).

So what we do instead is use the [`Form.Invoke`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyzhdc6b.aspx) method which guarantees that whatever we want to execute is execute in the form’s own thread. We pass an `Action` delegate to the `Invoke` method which contains the code that we want to execute. And that code is just updating the label.

---

<sup>1</sup> At least I couldn’t find anything in the documentation saying otherwise – the event *might* actually execute in the foreground thread but in that case the above code still works.

Comment: Yes, I know this. But i'm using a Console Application and I don't know how to use this in it.

Comment: @user1690292 well it’s even easier in a console application, just output the percentage to the console instead of to a label. Then you also don’t need the detour via `Invoke`.

Comment: Could you please write a short example for this, since I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Thank you, but how can I stop the console from closing. If I type in `Console.ReadLine` the percentage is shown in two lines.

Comment: The console only closes when you run the program from the IDE by pressing F5, because Visual Studio and Microsoft are retarded. A real console doesn’t close. In Visual Studio, you can use Ctrl+F5  instead just F5 to start the program to prevent the console from closing.